# calculate $\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

If $f$ is a continuous even function from $[-a,a]$ to $\Bbb R$ then calculate $\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx$

The answer that is given is $\int _{-a}^af(x)dx$

**My attempt**

$I=\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx=-\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)e^x}{1+e^x}dx+\int_{-a}^a {f(x)}dx$

Now for the first integral, we can use integration by parts but the equation is getting complicated and for the second integral would be $2\int_{0}^a {f(x)}dx$ as $f$ is even. Please help...

Comment: Note that the correct answer is $\frac 12 \int _{-a}^af(x)dx = \int _{0}^af(x)dx$

Comment: Yes @MartinR when I searched it, I didn't get it. Strange!! Where do you search by the way?

Comment: @Gimgim: With [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B-a%7D%5Ea%20%5Cfrac%7Bf(x)%7D%7B1%2Be%5Ex%7Ddx%24&p=1) – See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange.

Comment: More generally, if $f$ and $g$ are integrable, $f$ is even, and $g(x)+g(-x)=1$, then $\int_{-a}^a f(x)g(x)\,dx=\int_0^a f(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$I=\int^a_{-a} \frac {f(x)}{1+e^x} $$
Using **King property**:

Replace $x$ with $a+(-a)-x=-x$
$$I =\int^a_{-a} \frac {f(-x)}{1+e^{-x}}$$
Add both equations: $$2I= \int^a_{-a} \frac {f(x)}{1+e^{x}}+ \int^a_{-a} \frac {f(-x)}{1+e^{-x}}$$
$f(x)=f(-x)$ why?
$$2I =\int^a_{-a} \frac {f(x)}{1+e^{x}}+\int^a_{-a} \frac {f(x)\cdot e^x}{1+e^{x}}=\int_{-a}^af(x)$$

> $$I=\frac12  \int^a_{-a} {f(x)}=2\cdot \frac12  \int^a_{0} {f(x)}= \int^a_{0} {f(x)}$$